# ActiveJDBC concurrent requests?

Tags: concurrency, activejdbc

I am using [ActiveJDBC](http://code.google.com/p/activejdbc/) in one of my projects and today I ran into a nasty problem.

Concurrent requests to my application will fail, because ActiveJDBC tries to get multiple connections from pool with the same name "default".

There seems to be a possibility to open connection with different name, so instead of writing:

`Base.open(JNDI_NAME)`

one would write:

`new DB("someRandomName").open(JNDI_NAME);`

BUT... when trying to get some data from database, there is a problem: ActiveJDBC searches for connection "default" (or @DbName annotation from model class) - as I understand, this concept is used to handle multiple databases (not multiple connections).

I really don't want to replace ActiveJDBC, because thousands of lines of code is written - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ideas exist:)
In your code, you have:

```
new DB("someRandomName").open(JNDI_NAME);
```

..but the string you pass to constructor of class DB ***is not some random string***, and not JNDI name. It is a logical name of a database. You properly guessed that this has to to with access to multiple database access. 
Here is the doc explaining this:
http://javalite.io/database_connection_management#multiple-database-example

If you only have one database in your system, you do not even need a class DB, simply use Base:
http://javalite.github.io/activejdbc/snapshot/org/javalite/activejdbc/Base.html
It will ensure that database connections will have a name "default" - something your models expect

cheers